# using TabBarController

Tags: iphone, tabs, navigation, tabbar, viewcontroller

I'm developing a `TabBarController` application in iPhone.
In the First tab (Lets Say `Tab1`), I navigate the `viewControllers` for example (`view1`, `view2`, `view3`), now I'm on `view3` of `Tab1`, then I switch the tab and do some work there.  Now when I get back to `Tab1`, I'm on `view3`, but I want `Tab1` at `view1` position.

Comment: We could probably help you if you posted some code. How do you set up the tab bar controller?

Comment: [self.navigationController pushViewController:myTabBar animated:YES];
Connected the navigationController to the tab's navigation item in NIB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll sum it up, as I understood it:

Architecture:

- TabBar

  - ViewController1
  - ViewController1.1

    - ViewController1.1.1
  - ViewController2
  - ViewController3

So now you do the following:

ViewController1 -> ViewController1.1

ViewController1-1 ->
   ViewController1.1.1

ViewController1.1.1 ->
   ViewController3

ViewController3 -> ViewController1

and ViewController1.1.1 is displayed?

If so, just include the following in ViewController1.1 AND ViewController1.1.1

```
- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{    
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Yeah You understood it righty , and You Solved it too. Thanks Alot